# How to use the cryptosuite API for encryption in hyperledger fabric?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, public-key-encryption

I am trying to find an algorithm that will help encrypt data using the public key and decrypt using the private key in the smart contract. Cryptosuite is supposed to help achieve that but I can't find even one code example. Can you please explain what the '**opts**' parameter in this method is supposed to be and how its supposed to be used:

```
encrypt(key, plainText, opts)
```

Or if you know a better API or algorithm to do asymmetric encryption in hyperledger fabric.

Comment: The encrypt and decrypt methods in the  fabric node client sdk have no implementation. Not sure why they are even there.

Comment: So they really can't be used? Do you know any other way to encrypt data using these keys then?

Comment: I don't sorry. Fabric uses ECDSA so you could try to search for a library that does what you want.